# How to make ajax request from handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, ajax, handlebars.js, spotify

I'm trying to make an html table of a Spotify user's playlists and all the tracks in those playlists. I can get the playlist just fine.. However, to get the tracks in that playlist I need to make another request. I'm currently using a helper (get_track) to make the second request, and calling that as I iterate over each playlist. However it doesn't quite work.. Everything is returned undefined. Is there a better way to do this?

When I console log response.items from the request in the helper I get exactly the data I want, I just don't understant how to get that into my template...?

```
<script id="playlist-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>playlists</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>playlist</th>
      <th>tracks</th>
    </tr>
    {{#playlists.items}}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{name}}</a></td>
        <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>track name</th>
              </tr>
              {{log (get_track tracks.href)}}
              {{#each (get_track tracks.href)}}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{track.name}}</td>
                </tr>
              {{/each}}
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/playlists.items}}
  </table>
</script>




var playlistSource = document.getElementById('playlist-template').innerHTML,
playlistTemplate = Handlebars.compile(playlistSource),
playlistPlaceholder = document.getElementById('playlist');

    Handlebars.registerHelper('get_track', function(tracks){
      return $.ajax({
        url: tracks,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success: function(response) {
          return response.items;
        }
      });
    });
      if (access_token) {
        // render oauth info
        oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
          access_token: access_token,
          refresh_token: refresh_token
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(response) {
              userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

              $('#login').hide();
              $('#loggedin').show();
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(response) {
              playlistPlaceholder.innerHTML = playlistTemplate({Playlists: response}); //get playlists
              console.log(response);
              $('#login').hide();
              $('#loggedin').show();
            }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to display {{track.name}} from your ajax request you can't do it. The track.name has to be defined in your original data if you want it to be defined.
You can't modify the data that is passed to handlebar. However what you can do is to return the value of your track name in your helper and then it will be displayed in your template.
The last doubt that I have is about the synchronization : you have to synchronize your request in order to get a returned value in your helper otherwise it would be null : ajax is asynchonous so you have to wait the end of the ajax request with a while loop in order to return a value for your helper.

I hope I've been clear enough otherwise I'll try to be more accurate.